# cocos2d-x parallax node is not updating it child's position

Tags: android, cocos2d-x

I am adding multiple sprite to parallax Node to move all sprites in specific direction. When I move parallax node all sprites move along with but they didn't update their position. means 
their position remain same at which they all created.

this is my parallax node in which I am adding multiple sprites.

```
layerMoveLeft = CCParallaxNode::create();
this->addChild(layerMoveLeft);
```

here i am adding multiple sprites to parallax node.

```
for (int varX = 0; varX < 8; ++varX)
    {
        plate = new Plate(); // sprite object
        CCPoint pos = ccp(platesPosition,visibleSize.height/2.8);
        plate->setPosition(layerMoveLeft->convertToNodeSpace(pos));
        layerMoveLeft->CCNode::addChild(plate);
        plate->addComponent(new PlateAction());
        platesPosition = platesPosition + 190;

    }
```

the component I have added to  plate is new **plateAction()** but when I move parallax node all sprites move visually but they didn't change their position in the backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Position of sprites is relative to their parent node (which is layerMoveLeft in your case) and so they will not change their values, unless you change their position individually. To get each sprites absolute values, you need to add parent nodes position to their position.

Comment: you are right but i got another idea that put all sprites in an array and moved all sprites using for loop.